# Zoom FFT shifting region of interest to be centered at zero Hz

Tags: fft

So using this resource:

https://flylib.com/books/en/2.729.1/the_zoom_fft.html

I think I understand that the zoom FFT allows you to calculate the FFT for a region of interest with a lower order FFT by shifting the region of interest to near zero Hz and filtering out frequencies outside of the shifted region of interest, after which we can compute the FFT with a smaller relative-to-zero Hz frequency range to capture the region of interest which means we don't need the FFT to consider as many points to cover our smaller frequency range.

However, I am confused about the process shifting the region of interest to be centered at 0 Hz. As I understand it the DFT returns only positive frequencies, so I don't really know why we shift the region of interest to have portions at negative frequencies. Is there any reason not to just shift the region of interest to start at 0 Hz and then filter the complex frequency shifted signal with a lowpass decimating filter and then compute the FFT on the resulting signal?

Comment: The DFT is defined for positive frequencies, but because of the periodicity, the upper half of the positive frequencies can be considered the negative frequencies.

Comment: I'd like to see how this compares to just running a DTFT over the frequencies of interest. Unless you need the absolute lowest computational load, the DTFT is likely to be much easier to use.